# Implementing python code for grouping purchase based on genre

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following table(df) having following attributes

```
 id      purchase date    genre(music, drama, horror..) 
23      1/1/2020          music
23      1/2/2020          horror
24      5/2/2020           drama
```

I want to generate table having

```
id      count of purchases     no.of purchasesin music     no.ofpurchasesin horror  noofpurchasedrama
23             2                   1                                1                    0
24             1                    0                               0                     1
```

I have tried the following code:

```
a = df.groupby('id').agg({'purchasedate': lambda a: a.count()})
 But how to get new attributes of genre?
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it really have to be columns for the count values? What if other genres are added in the future? That would change the column count of your result table, and depending on how you did it, maybe you'd even have to change your code.

Instead you could do the following, which gives you one row per occuring id and genre combination with the number of purchases of that setting added:

```
df.groupby(['id', "genre"]).size().reset_index(name="purchases")
```

```
   id   genre  purchases
0  23  horror          1
1  23   music          1
2  24   drama          1
```

And for the total values, use a second query

```
df.groupby('id').size().reset_index(name="total_purchases")
```

```
   id  total_purchases
0  23                2
1  24                1
```

It's a bit different in structure from what you asked for, but it scales well with a growing list of genres in your database.